# iOS Spotlight search for, then edit a contact

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I can't for the life of me understand how, in iOS 10.3.1, I do what I've done many times before iOS 9/10, namely:

1. Spotlight search for a contact
2. Then edit that contact

This is what I see:

[image: best search hit]

*Best search hit*

[image: selecting the contact]

*Cancel, Notes, Share Contact*

I.e. no way to edit nor to view it in the contacts app. I don't have 3D Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your second screenshot, 3D Touch on the profile photo, then tap on the name at the top of the popup to open the contact in Contacts.app.

[Without 3D Touch, this is not possible.](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30944902) To search contacts, you can use the Search bar at the top of the Contacts or Phone apps.

Comment: I have a 4" phone without 3D Touch :-/

Comment: @Andreas Does a long press work?

Comment: @Andreas It appears you're out of luck according to a thread over on ASC (edited answer with link). That seems pretty ridiculous

Comment: I'll give you a ☑️ and apple a ‍♂️. You get someone's new details and try to edit their contact card in front of them, and it takes forever because you start by walking down a dead end. It's embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks @grgarside, but I'm another one of these people out of luck. I can't see why they had to change this from previous versions of iOS. Dang!